# Cannot connect to Spark through sparklyr in RStudio

Tags: sparklyr

I connect to spark using this code:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

Got some error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1006)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @13545af8
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
    ... 13 more
```

I figured out that this may be some problem with spark configuration, but don't know how to deal with this issue. Is it related to Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the Java version. A lower Java version would work. Please see the [link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-connect-rstudio-desktop-to-spark-through-sparklyr/133362?u=jinghong_zeng) for my solution.